# IOS Splash Screen / NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios

Okay I have been fallowing a tutorial because I would like the NSUserDefaults to load any information possible on the splash screen.

I fallowed this tutorial

```
 http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-11-Saving-data-using-NSUserDefaults
```

It helped me learn how things are saved but here is my issue he has it display that information through a button click with a label getting ride of that label has been a huge issue.

What I am trying to do is make a splash screen that will ask if the user has saved data then send them to this view controller and ask them to enter some information and delete the saved data if they don't then send them to this view controller and have them asked for some data to be saved.

I am very lost on how to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This question is really broad, but if you're just wanting to know how to save data into NSUserDefaults you do:

**Set it:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:yourBooleanValue forKey:@"yourKeyIndicatingTheDataWasSaved"];
```

**And retrieve it:**

```
BOOL boolIndicatingIfDataWasSaved = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"yourKeyIndicatingTheDataWasSaved"];
```

You should check the docs on the other methods and data types to save into [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)